# mixing tenses in a sentence with "while"

Tags: tense-agreement, backshifting

The following is an excerpt from the Washington Post article, titled "When did the world turn against Justin Timberlake and embrace Britney Spears?":

> They had a bad break-up three years later. **While no one really *knows* what really happened, the tabloids had a pretty good idea.** As Buzzfeed points out, magazines like Us Weekly were clearly Team Timberlake, intimating that Spears cheated on him. And Timberlake implied as much with a Spears doppelganger in his famous “Cry Me a River” video.
>
> ([source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2016/08/26/when-did-the-world-turn-on-justin-timberlake-and-embrace-britney-spears/#comments))

I am having trouble understanding why the author wrote: "knows" instead of "knew". On a paragraph level, the main tense is set in the past mood; on a sentence level, it is supposed to be "knew" because what the writer meant was that people did not know when the tabloids had a good idea.

Later in the article, the writer wrote:

> "In true Taylor Swiftian coy style, he’ll never confirm it’s about Spears. But everyone **knows** it’s Spears, and he’s referred to her in many interviews."

So there's no reasoning that the writer used "knows" because people still don't know.

I recently have been bothered by the mixing of tenses, especially on a sentence level. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: I think "..he knows.." imply that still no one knows what really happened.

Comment: This is an interesting question, because things like it come up regularly on ELL, which makes me wonder how other languages handle this issue.  In general, there is no reason you can't mix tenses in an English sentence, as long as it makes sense.  What is your native language, and is this forbidden in your native language?  Can you really not say "Yesterday they ate rice, but today I eat beans"?

Comment: For true incorrect tense mixing after *while*, see, [“While she is sleeping, we...” – what verb tense comes next?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22875/while-she-is-sleeping-we-what-verb-tense-comes-next)

Comment: @stangdon Thank you for the comment. My native language is Korean. Actually, unlike English speakers, we don't pay close attention to verb tense. For example, we don't have the perfect tense. So, it is the other way around. While we can definitely say "Yesterday they ate rice, but today I eat beans", I still often make errors with tenses when writing in English, such as when using the words "not until" or "before". This is because we don't really differentiate tenses that much in Korean. I think this is why some Koreans suffer from tense agreement issues.

Comment: @stangdon The other aspect that is starkly different from English is the article and countable/non-countable noun issue. This is not really specified in Korean, either.

Comment: @Luxembourg - Thank you for the explanation!  It's always good to learn about how other language differ from English, because it helps explain some of the questions that people have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**While** there means *although*.

Although no one *can say* all that really happened, the story told by tabloids was close to the truth.

The *although*-clause simply refers to the present state of knowledge.  There is no sense with *while*, as it is used here, that the lack of knowledge was *concurrent* with the story in the tabloids, that it existed *during* the same time frame.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did not know that "while" was used like an "although" meaning in the context.

Comment: You're welcome. While your title mentions "mixing tenses", your question was not really about mixing tenses :)